# How to over ride php file in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, overrides, date

I want to do some changes in

```
vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Date.php
```

How can I override the file in app folder?

Comment: What is the purpose of your rewrite?

Comment: @AmitBera changed the script in that as per my requirements

Comment: @AmitBera Can u say how to do that?

Comment: You can try the plugin for it.

Comment: @Nafisa May I know on which 2.3.* version you trying?

Answer (score 2):

I don't prefer to use `<preference></preference>` for this work.

If you want some modification at any public method of any class then I suggest use [**Plugin**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)  instead of `preference`.

**`<preference>`** means class override where `<plugin>` means method function/method override.

**Step 1:** Create di.xml at{YourVendorNAME}/{ModuleName}/etc/di.xml.This is the declaration of the plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Date">
        <plugin name="DateTime_plugin" type="{YourVendorNAME}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\DatePlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step2:** Create `DatePlugin.php` at  `{YourVendorNAME}/{ModuleName}/Plugin`,

```
<?php
namespace {YourVendorNAME}\{ModuleName}\Plugin;
class DatePlugin
{

    public function beforeDate(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Date $subject,
        $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 
        $input = null
    ){
        return [$format,$input];
    }
}
```

**Here, i have created a before  plugin on \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Date::date() function .**

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Date" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Date"/>
```

and create class for **Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Date** and extend the **\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Date**

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Can you tell me where is the validation for the datepicker is done. Where can i get the code?